# Helm timeout for cronjob with a persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I have a Kubernetes cron job in AWS EKS that requires a persistent volume, so this is roughly what I have:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name:  pvc-{{$.Release.Name}}-tmp
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Then it's mounted to a cronjob (the mount part is correct, as the following shows)

All are deployed with Helm, and a fresh deployment times out, because the PVC remains in the `Pending` state with the message `waiting for the first consumer to be created before binding`. If during the deployment I create a new job based on the cron job, the PVC is immediately bound and this and all subsequent deployment work like expected.

Is it possible to either make a PVC bind "eagerly", without a pod that requires it or, preferably, not to wait for it to get bound during the chart installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the storage class that you use? Storage class has `volumeBindingMode` attributes that controls how PV is dynamically created.

The `volumeBindingMode` could be `Immediate` and `WaitForFirstConsumer` mode.

For checking the storage class you can do `kubectl get storageclass` or `kubectl describe storageclass`. The default storage class will be used if not specified on the K8 PVC definition.

References:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode

Comment: I have only one storage class in the cluster, will now try adding a new one with the `Immediate` mode.